# Dynamic key in typescript type

Tags: typescript

Suppose a type key has this format: `XXX_{placeholder1}_{placeholder2}` where `placeholder1` could be `a,b,c,...,z`, same for `placeholder2`.
Instead of explicitly defining

```
type ObjectT = {
  XXX_a_a: '...',
  XXX_a_b: '...',
  ....
  XXX_z_z: '...'
}
```

Is there any way I could dynamically generate those keys? I know I could use

```
type ObjectT = {
  [key: string]: string
}
```

But it's too generate, and I want a more restricted type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) !

```
type az = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | ... | 'z'

type keys = `XXX_${az}_${az}`;

type ObjectT = Record<keys,string>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAhgXlAvFA5DFUA+qBGHsoDG+qcKAUOaJFANYQgDOSUABgBqcD6AJAN7wAvrwFxBrANyVq0API4AVhELAAKiwBKygPYAnACYAeekwA0URsF0BLAHYBzAHyVKQA)